# How to write the "and" character at the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

Does anybody know how to write the "and" character at the keyboard? like as the code bellow:

```js
console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
```

Comment: Shift and 7 ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hold shift and press 7               _